# Android getting items from a list view

Tags: android

I have a dialog with a listView and OK button,

```
id  text
radiobutton1  radiobutton2 
---------------------------
id  text
radiobutton1  radiobutton2 
---------------------------
id  text
radiobutton1  radiobutton2 
--------------------------

       buttonOK
```

I like to get "id" and "selected radio button" for the list.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever you want to do processing with the views in a ListView you need to create a custom adapter that will handle your logic implementation and pass that information to the views as necessary.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as an answer if it solved your question! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set an `OnClickListener` for each of radiobuttons inside of the `getView()` method in your Adapter, and then save the result to a boolean array stored inside your adapter.

Comment: How do I call getView on click of that OK button?

Comment: Oh I assumed that since you were using a Listview with radio buttons in it that you had created your own custom adapter class. How are you defining your Listview if you did not create your own adapter?

Comment: Sorry, I missed out on that info. I am using SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that with SimpleCursorAdapter, I have always just made my own adapter in the past. Sorry.